# Sqlalchemy post_update for relationship seems not working for me

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have 2 models (sqlalchemy 0.9) which references to each other (simplified and with integers as id)

```
class Device(SyncableModel):
    __tablename__ = 'devices'
    ...
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    current_program_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('programs.id', use_alter=True, name='fk_current_program'))

    current_program = relationship(
        'Program', backref = backref('current_for_device', uselist=False),
        primaryjoin="Device.current_program_id==Program.id",
        post_update=True
    )
    programs = relationship(
        'Program', backref='device', lazy='joined',
         cascade="all, delete-orphan",
         primaryjoin="Device.id==Program.device_id"
    )


class Program(SyncableModel):
    __tablename__ = 'programs'
    ...
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    device_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('devices.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    name = db.Column(db.String(64))
```

And i need to make this:

```
device = Device()
device.id = 1
program = Program()
program.id = 2
program.device_id = device.id
device.current_program_id = program.id
db.session.add_all([device, program,])
db.session.commit()
```

But i'm getting:

```
IntegrityError: (IntegrityError) (1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`cloud2`.`devices`, CONSTRAINT `fk_current_program` FOREIGN KEY (`current_program_id`) REFERENCES `programs` (`id`))') 'UPDATE devices SET created=%s, updated=%s, name=%s, rain_detected=%s, current_program_id=%s, timezone=%s, synced=%s WHERE devices.id = %s' (datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 11, 19, 48, 23), datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 11, 19, 48, 26), 'nWhosie', 0, '\xeaL\xff\x80\xe5\xffC2\x9a)\xe5\x86\xe4\xad}l', 'America/Chicago', datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 11, 19, 48, 27), '\xd4\xe3\x04;:\xa0M\xce\x95\x9a\xf9U\x05x"\x10')
```

*Note: i'm using not int ids in real*

I thought that with post_update=True it will work as expected. What am i doing wrong?

Thanks!

**Update**
As @gsb-eng mentioned the root of the problem should be in missing explicit relationship setting. But it is a problem as objects are generated from list of dicts and it would be hard to find out all relations.

**Update 2**
Finally i was able to fix relationships with the help of inspect:

```
def fix_relationships(objs):
    for obj in objs:
        insp = inspect(type(obj))
        for relation in insp.relationships:
            if relation.post_update:
                # A relation to be set
                relation_key = relation.key
                if getattr(obj, relation_key):
                    # Relation had already been set
                    continue
                foreign_key = relation.primaryjoin.left.key
                target_class_name = relation.argument.arg
                target_key = relation.primaryjoin.right.key
                fk = getattr(obj, foreign_key)
                if not fk:
                    # Nothing to set.
                    continue
                for o in objs:
                    if o.__class__.__name__ == target_class_name \
                            and getattr(o, target_key) == fk:
                        setattr(obj, relation_key, o)
                        setattr(obj, foreign_key, None)
                        break
```

Comment: Which db are you using?

Comment: Seems to work without exception for Python 3.8 and SQLAlchemy 1.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I observed your below error it is trying to insert this value for our program `current_program_id='\xeaL\xff\x80\xe5\xffC2\x9a)\xe5\x86\xe4\xad}l'`, and that should be an integer value as it defined.

```
UPDATE devices SET created=%s, updated=%s, name=%s, rain_detected=%s, current_program_id=%s, timezone=%s, synced=%s WHERE devices.id = %s' (datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 11, 19, 48, 23), datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 11, 19, 48, 26), 'nWhosie', 0, '\xeaL\xff\x80\xe5\xffC2\x9a)\xe5\x86\xe4\xad}l', 'America/Chicago', datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 11, 19, 48, 27), '\xd4\xe3\x04;:\xa0M\xce\x95\x9a\xf9U\x05x"\x10')
```

Ideally it shouldn't fire the `UPDATE` query since you didn't mention the relationship, `device.current_program = program` defines the actual relationship between those two objects.May you better try running this....

```
device = Device()
device.id = 1
program = Program()
program.id = 2
device.current_program = program
device.programs = [program]
db.session.add_all([device, program,])
db.session.commit()
```

Comment: >that should be an integer value as it defined - yes, i'm using not integers ids. Code i showed is simplification

Comment: `since you didn't mention the relationship, device.current_program = program` - makes sense. The problem is that objects are generated from long list of dicts in abstract algorithm and i could set only ids. Is there any way around? I mean make post_update work without mentioning relationship

Comment: @SerafimSuhenky Intention behind `post_update` is to solve this `bidirectional` relationships, you've to define the `relationship` then  only `SqlALchemy` does the right `update` before `Insert` or `delete` happens.

Comment: Thanks, finally i was able to solve my issue with your help. One thing to mention: if you set both relationship and foreign key, post_update wouldn't  fire